# Populating constant value using grafana Table panel plugin

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-variable

I am trying to generate a dashboard report as below.

It has 3 columns (Service uptime list, expected and actual %).

I am using Table panel in Grafana and populated first 2 columns using `max(up) by (service)`. Service list is getting populated from db source and calculating service up time.

Now, I am trying to populate 3rd column, which is 100 (constant) for all available rows.

Pls suggest, how to populate constant value for all available rows in table panel in grafana?

After that, I need to compare column 3 & column 2 and color as per results.  (if equal then green, or red)

For populating first 2 columns, I am querying the db source and getting `max(up) by (service)`.  In order to populate the 3rd column, I used an expr as `100`, but it was not worked. 3rd column showed as empty only.

```
max(up) by (service)

expr: 100
```

Need 3 columns, in which 1st column shows service list, 2nd is actual %. 3rd column is constant 100 and need to compare column 2 and 3 and highlight with color.

Comment: What datasource are you using

Comment: Prometheus data source